# Should I use Cookies or Isolated Storage to store a small amount of data for a Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, cookies, isolatedstorage

I have a Silverilght app that needs to store a small amount of data (user preferences stuff) on the client.  Should I store it using cookies, or using Silverlight's Isolated Storage?  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use isolated storage in most cases for the following reasons:

- Isolated storage will work in out-of-browser scenario
- Isolated storage will survive if user deletes cookies in the browsers
- Code using isolated storage is more portable
- Code to save user preference to isolated storage is simpler (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: isolated storage can be deleted as well and what do you mean by 'portable'?

Comment: Yes, isolated storage can be deleted, but most browsers offer delete cookies option and isolated storage will survive that. Portable = isolated storage code will work without changes or with minor changes on Windows Phone 7.1/8, Xbox, Windows 8

Comment: When migrating from Silverlight to Windows Phone 7.1/8, Xbox or Windows 8, Isolated Storage is the very least of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Both Isolated Storage and Cookies will solve the problem of saving user preferences on the local machine. If the user may log in from different machines you should save the user preferences on the server side. For this you will have to implement your own service for saving user preferences. Retrieving user preferences should be doing during the login procedure.